# Template parameter as return type

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

I stumbled upon this some time ago and I finally need to get an answer to this!

The problem is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class FIRST, class SECOND>

FIRST multiply(FIRST a, SECOND b){
    return a * b;
}

int main(){
    int x = 39;
    double y = 38.38;
    cout << multiply(x, y) << endl;
}
```

In this C++ code I have two template parameters and the return type of the function is the type of one parameter. My problem with that is that the return type has to be (in this case) the same type like the variable `a` is. I tried it with a THIRD template parameter but it gave me an compiling error, could anyone please explain this to me?

I don't want to make it generally a `long` or something, I want the return type to be the 'biggest' type of the variables passed, so that it will work with chars and strings as well (for those I would obviously do another operation or something, this is only an example).

Comment: You might want to correct your terminology. You have one *function template* with two *template parameters.*

Comment: Thanks for that, since I can't say yet

Comment: Why do you want the return type to be like `a`, which is `int` in your example? `int` * `double` gives you `double` and, basically, you lose a fraction when return `int` from the result of operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical approach to deal with situations like this is to return the appropriate type returned from the result of the operation called:

```
template <typename FIRST, typename SECOND>
auto multiply(FIRST a, SECOND b) -> decltype(a * b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

This use-case is pretty much the motivating example for adding late return types: the result type of an operation can be entirely non-predictable. This leads to two needs:

1. It needs to be possible to determine the type of an expression which is what `decltype(expr)` does: it yields the type of what `expr` is declared to be: when `expr` is a function call you'd look at the function declaration and that's what `decltype(expr)` yields (well, there are some complexities in there).
2. To actually formulate `expr` it is frequently necessary to get hold of function arguments. Thus, a new approach to declare function was introduced:

   `auto` *function-name*`(`*args*`) ->` *return-type*

   The `auto` keyword is merely indicating that the function will use a *late return type*. The *function-name* and *args* are used the same as in other functino declaration. The *return-type* then follows at a point where parameter names can be used, i.e., after the `->` is the *return->type* which is is normally in front of the function declaration.

   Put differently, if *return-type* does *not* refer to the names of arguments, the declaration above is equivalent to this declaration:

   *return-type* *function-name*`(`*args*`)`

   If *return-type* refers to a name introduced in *args* you'd need to deal with getting object of the appropriate types, e.g., using `std::declval<T>()`.

Comment: Note that in C++14 you don't need the `decltype`, templates can deduce an `auto` return type.

Comment: Well, thanks, but I wouldn't exactly know what aut and decltype does since I'm only at a level of half a year self-learning C++. I can about guess what it does and why but would you mind explaining it a bit further in detail?

Comment: I didn't know about that site yet so thank you very much! I guess this'll save me quite some trouble from now on ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
typename std::common_type<FIRST,SECOND>::type
```

as return type of your arithmetic expression.

Comment: Needs a `typename` in front.

Comment: @Angew: strictly speaking, `typename` is to tell the *compiler* that it is a type. I'm talking to a human ... made an edit.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work, e.g., when `FIRST` and `SECOND` are non-square matrices: multiplying `matrix<10, 5>` and `matrix<5, 3>` would yield a `matrix<10, 5>`.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl: no, it doesn't. But, to compensate, it will work also for variadic scalar operations, `template <typename ... Args>
auto multiply(Args ... args) -> typename std::common_type<Args ...>::type`, where with the `decltype` approach you have more difficulties.