# no instance of function template matches the argument list i dont know why

Tags: c++, windows

no instance of function template matches the argument list is the error.
I have already tried to remove the template then it works but i dont see why this should not work.

```
template <class T>
T read(SIZE_T adress)
{
    T returnBuffer = 0;
    ReadProcessMemory(0, (LPCVOID)adress, &returnBuffer, sizeof(T), 0);
    return returnBuffer;
}

uint32_t local = read((SIZE_T)0x1714FE8);
```

Comment: How should the compiler know that type `T` the function template should be instantiated for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template parameter as return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761206/template-parameter-as-return-type)

Comment: For any future questions, I will recommend removing custom types as it can help others see errors and experiment on their own much quicker. I would also avoid C-style casts if you're working with C++.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the return type alone to coax a type deduction. Your last line needs to read like this:

`uint32_t local = read<uint32_t>((SIZE_T)0x1714FE8);`

or

`uint32_t local = read<decltype(local)>((SIZE_T)0x1714FE8);`

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cyA3YK)