# Use C++ templates to return multiple data types that depend on the function logic

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this code that declares two different structs and a class with a method that receives a string and decides which struct type to return in runtime.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A { int integerValue; };

struct B { double doubleValue; };

class Evaluate
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static T parse(std::string);
};

template <typename T>
T Evaluate::parse(std::string value)
{
    if (value == "A")
    {
        A a;
        a.integerValue = 8;
        return a;
    }
    else if (value == "B")
    {
        B b;
        b.doubleValue = 8.8;
        return b;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Value type not supported");
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto intResult = Evaluate::parse("A");
    auto doubleResult = Evaluate::parse("B");

    std::cout << intResult.integerValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << doubleResult.integerValue << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm trying to use a template to set a variable return type that depends on the method logic, but despite having no errors in the method declaration, when I use it, I have the following error:

> no instance of function template "Evaluate::parse" matches the argument listC/C++(304) 
> main.cpp(44, 22): argument types are: (const char [2])

[image]

Am I doing it right? Is it even possible to use templates in this case?

I need to figure this out because in my actual code: https://github.com/timbergus/gps-playground, I have in the `gps.h` class 7 virtually identical functions that return different structures depending on the sample type, and I want to reduce them to only one `parse` function.

Please, help

Comment: What you are attempting to do will never work, since the return type must be known as compile-time, but the string is parsed at runtime. So, you will have to use `std::variant<A,B>` (or equivalent) for the return type, and then the caller can determine which type is contained in the returned `variant` and extract and use the appropriate value as needed.

Comment: I read something related to this but wasn't sure if it was the proper approach. Thanks a lot for your help. I will give it a try ‍♂️

Comment: You are right; sorry for the confusion, and thank you for the corrections.

Comment: This isn't how you write a parser. Suppose you are parsing an `int`, then your program should already know that an `int` is expected here and consequently pass that information into the parsing function. What you're doing is getting the lowest level function to guess whatever structure the input string should have, which is impossible.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I'm trying to learn some C++ because I like the language, and I thought working on a GPS module would be a cool project. I named it parser because I was trying to extract the information received from the satellite. This information contains the key to knowing which type of structure I need to store the data extracted, and the number of data structures is finite, so I tried to figure out if C++ could guess which one was the right one to return. Maybe I should call the method "sampleAnalyzer" or "sampleDataExtractor" instead.

Comment: Another alternative may be to return an union? Or a common base class for the two structs?

Comment: That last one is a great idea. Maybe I can use a common struct with all the possible options and use only the ones needed for each struct at a time. The ones unused by the struct returned each time will remain empty. I am not sure if that was your proposal, @AndrewBloom.

Comment: *"despite having no errors in the method declaration"* -- This is not entirely accurate. A template is not fully checked for errors until it is instantiated. What you see it not "no errors" but something more like "no structural errors"; your braces are matched and the non-dependent identifiers are known. To instantiate the template (and see the errors in it), you would need to specify a template argument, as in `Evaluate::parse<A>("A")`.

Comment: Ah! That is why I thought the code was correct  Thanks, @JaMiT. That removes the usage error in `auto intResult = Evaluate::parse<A>("A");` but it breaks in another ten places while building the project 

Comment: For your immediate error: [no instance of function template matches the argument list i dont know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533031). However, calling that a duplicate seems like it is side-stepping the real issue that templates do not do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm getting the idea that the problem here is that I'm trying to use something inappropriate for the task  I will try the solutions you gave me tomorrow, guys. I appreciate your time and patience ‍♂️ Sorry if I stop answering, but here it's 2:30 AM. I have in my list: `std::variant`, using a `union` type or a common structure for all of them.

Comment: *I'm trying to learn some C++ because I like the language, and I thought working on a GPS module would be a cool project.* -- That's all well and good, but here is the issue -- C++ is one of the most difficult languages out there -- before using it for projects, you need to know the language to a great degree, and not just "learning it".  That can only be done after months (and sometimes years) of learning the language through using proper training material.  Too many persons want to do the "cool stuff" without learning the language properly, and that will not work out too well.

Comment: I understand it @PaulMcKenzie. C++ is the Dark Souls of the programming languages. I don't pretend to work as a C++ developer. It's only for personal projects. I know I'm far from understanding the language deeply enough to use it professionally, but I'm a practical learner. I've always found it easier to learn by doing, so when I approach a difficult task, I try to find a motivating project and learn as I encounter problems. I have seen some video tutorials that gave me the basics, but for more complex issues, this is the only place I know where there are people with the knowledge I lack 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the method can return `A` or `B`(or some other types)... how the caller side handle the returned object?

Since `A` and `B`(and others) are not common type, you'll have to write several process codes for each types, and decide which code should be used based on the type of returned object:

```
if( A returned ){  ProcessFor_A;  }
else if( B returned ){  ProcessFor_B;  }
...
```

If you are considering such caller side code... I guess, it can be changed to as:

```
//Not template. Added the 2nd argument
void ParseMethod( const std::string &value, ResultReceiver &Rcvr )
{
  if( value == "A" )
  {
    A a;
    Rcvr.Receive( a );  //instead of return, call the method of ResultReceiver which argument type is 'A`.
  }
  elsd if( value == "B" )
  {
    B b;
    Rcvr.Receive( b );  //instead of return, call the method of ResultReceiver which argument type is 'B`.
  }
  else ...
}
```

In this case,

> several process codes for each types

are written as methods of `ResultReceiver` ( `Receive( const A& )`, `Receive( const B& )`, etc ).

Comment: So, instead of returning the struct, I pass a reference to it (Rcvr) and, using the value parameter, decide which of the internal logic of the parser should modify it. That could work too. Thanks a lot, I will try it.

Comment: I'm also trying to use `std::any` and `std::any_cast<A>` to get the proper structure knowing the condition I pass to the parser, but it's a work in progress.

Comment: I have created a small GitHub project (https://github.com/timbergus/types-playground) to illustrate the `std::any`. I will use it to try the rest of the solutions you gave me.

Comment: I guess, there is no need to report the progress of your try. (What can be information is "result".)